# Ist this $\mathbb{R}$-algebra finitely generated?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Consider the $\mathbb{R}$-algebra 
$$
B=\{f\in \mathbb{R}[T]\mid f(n)=c\text{ for some $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$}\}
$$
i.e. the those polynomials $f\in  \mathbb{R}[T]$ which have the same value $f(n)$ for every integer $n\in\mathbb{R}$.

I think intuitively, that $B$ is not finitely generated as an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. Is this true and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f \in B$ and $f(n) = c$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$ then the polynomial $f - c$ has infinitely many roots, hence it's $0$.  So $B = \mathbb R$ is finitely generated as an $\mathbb R$-algebra (take $1$ as a generator).